# How to handle date between India Time on Client side and Server date in US Time via mongo

Tags: mongodb, time, date-range

I have an app where the client location will be in India. My application has to aggregate data based on the daterange client has given. So if the client gives 14-Dec-2016 to 21-Dec-2016. It should search on from 14-Dec-2016 00:00:00am to 21-Dec-2016 23:59:59pm. 
Now as soon as I send my date to my server it get converted to
`Dec 13 2016 18:30:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)`
`Dec 21 2016 18:29:59 GMT+0000 (UTC)`
Now I write my aggregation query as

```
let cursor = Trip.aggregate([{
        $match: {
            startTime: {
                $gte: startDate.toDate(),
                $lte: endDate.toDate()
            },
        }
    },{
        $group: {
            _id: {
                date: {
                    $dayOfMonth: "$startTime"
                },
                month: {
                    $month: "$startTime"
                },
                year: {
                    $year: "$startTime"
                }
            },
            count: {
                $sum: 1
            }
        }
    }]);
```

Which results in following output

```
[ { _id: { date: 17, month: 12, year: 2016 }, count: 2 },
  { _id: { date: 16, month: 12, year: 2016 }, count: 2 },
  { _id: { date: 13, month: 12, year: 2016 }, count: 2 } ]
```

The actual time the trip took place was

```
"startTime" : ISODate("2016-12-13T20:10:20.381Z")
"startTime" : ISODate("2016-12-13T19:54:56.855Z")
```

Which actually took place on `14-12-2016 01:40:20am` and `14-12-2016 01:24:56am`

I want all things to be in one time-range but MongoDB does not allow to store data in any other time range other than UTC and it is getting difficult to manage different times in client-side query and database.
How should I go about solving it?

Comment: One solution I can think of is storing data as timestamp in milliseconds from Epoch, but will that help?

Comment: I think you should keep timezone related logic in client. Get the timezone client is in and change the UTC datetimes back into client time zone. I'm not sure what problems you are facing while doing that.

Comment: The problem is mongodb's aggregation algorithm. For date as `ISODate("2016-12-13T20:10:20.381Z")` it aggregates on date as 13, 12, 2016. Which is correct. But not something that I want. According to me, the solution you have come up is to take all the data to front end and do all calculations there. Which will add to frontend logic a lot and something I personally hate doing. Other approach will be ditching the mongodb aggregation framework and writing my own aggregation logic over dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approach the following way. You can save the records with offset millis. So your collection will look like something below.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("585a97dcaceaaa5d2254aeb5"),
    "start_date": ISODate("2016-12-17T00:00:00Z"),
    "offsetmillis": -19080000
} {
    "_id": ObjectId("585a97dcaceaaa5d2254aeb6"),
    "start_date": ISODate("2016-11-17T00:00:00Z"),
    "offsetmillis": -19080000
} {
    "_id": ObjectId("585a97dcaceaaa5d2254aeb7"),
    "start_date": ISODate("2016-11-13T00:00:00Z"),
    "offsetmillis": -19080000
}
```

And you can update the aggregation query to include the offset millis while processing.

```
aggregate([{
    $match: {
        start_date: {
            $gte: new ISODate("2016-01-01"),
            $lte: new ISODate("2016-12-31")
        },
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            date: {
                $dayOfMonth: {
                    $add: ["$start_date", "$offsetmillis"]
                }
            },
            month: {
                $month: {
                    $add: ["$start_date", "$offsetmillis"]
                }
            },
            year: {
                $year: {
                    $add: ["$start_date", "$offsetmillis"]
                }
            }
        },
        count: {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
}]);
```

Sample Response

```
{ "_id" : { "date" : 12, "month" : 11, "year" : 2016 }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "date" : 16, "month" : 11, "year" : 2016 }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "date" : 16, "month" : 12, "year" : 2016 }, "count" : 1 }
```

You can optimize it more but I think this will give you an idea.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks buddy