# How to maintain Timezone

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nodes

My client is in india and server in USA . If user submit his post from india it get stored in USA server so when i display post submit time to user it is as per USA time . I want to show it as per clients timezone

Comment: js dates don't have a timezone, they are just numbers, so you should be able to simply reformat them.

Comment: See if this helps you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41264307/how-to-handle-date-between-india-time-on-client-side-and-server-date-in-us-time/41265842#41265842

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to handle timezones is to work with [Epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) behind the scenes, and translate it to the user's preferred timezone on render (or with client-side code).

Epoch time is the number of seconds since it became 1 January 1970 in London. For example, right now the time is 1483130714. This means we've got one simple number, that can be effortlessly compared and sorted, to represent precise moments without needing to care about dates, timezones, locales and their frustrating details. Virtually all languages in popular use have the ability to parse these numbers into their own timestamp values. In JavaScript, you can do this with `new Date(1483130714)`. You'll get a date object and you can then present that however you like (eg with `toLocaleString`).

If you don't use Epoch time, you'd want to use UTC, the next-best thing. The important thing is to store in a consistent universally-understood format and then translate it to the user's preferred form as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store date in UTC and then convert it as per browser culture and timezone. So store all dates in UTC and depending on browser culture you can add offset, this could be tricky if user sets wrong culture and time.